# Contacts in Outlook 2003/2007, some questions

Tags: microsoft-outlook, smtp, contacts

1. If I create a distribution list and then select members, can I see different fields than the default ones? In 2007 there are radio buttons for 'name only' and 'more columns', but the latter does seem to only result in no results at all, regardless of which address book I choose. In 2003 there is no such thing.
2. Is there a plug in that will break up the recipients (whether they be to, cc, or bcc) in groups of X, and send then a number of mails as required? Our host allows only 50 recipients per mail and only 300 total recipients per 5 minutes. I know the email client blat has exactly this functionality, but it does not seem to be able to connect to the exchange server to get the contacts needed. Could I maybe set outlook to send to blat which then does the breaking up as necessary?
3. Can I (or is there a plug in for this) export only part of the contacts instead of all of them?

Note that we send mail outside our organisation via our web host where we've got a few mailboxes, and we use our exchange (2000) server only internally, the few people that can send email to the outside world have an external mailbox as well as their exchange account defined. I might be able to convince our general boss that we can simply give (some) people the ability to send outside via exchange, but I might just as well not succeed.

Alternatively, is there another program that can connect to exchange to get the contacts (selected based on categories) and then send via smtp in groups with delays between the mails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - the more columns radio button applies to the Search field.  The default is to search the name.  To see the member of the list, you have to double click the entry.  While I'm sure you could write an addin to do what you want, I'm not aware of anything that exists

2 - perhaps some VBA code behind a custom form would allow you to solve the problem.

3 - you could write an LDAP query against AD to dig this information out.

Almost any mail client can access Exchange via POP or IMAP if these protocols are enabled on the server.  Which might have the feature you need I do not know.

\\Greg

Comment: Thanks,

1 So it only searches the columns already displayed (name, display name, email address), right?

2 & 3, I might try that, which should be interesting considering I know very little of vba and ldap protocol.

So far I've not found an email client that has exactly what I need, but I'll keep looking